# Hide Dropdown When Clicking Tab key on the keyboard

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a dropdown list in my lightning component. When you start typing on the input area, a dropdown will appear and list all the categories that matches the keyword being typed. However, if I press the Tab key on the keyboard, the dropdown should disapppear. How to get around the code if onkeyup is already used for getting the records appearing on the dropdown.

Comment: You could use an if-else in your onkeyup handler, or you could use onblur, which might be preferable to cover situations where the user moves out of the area with the mouse or by touch as well.

Comment: onblur only works if I move the mouse outside of the dropdown. It doesn't work if I click the Tab key.

Comment: By the way, is it okay to have onkeyup and onblur at once?

Comment: Yes, you can have them both. onblur should work... we would need to see the relevant code to help you figure out what;s wrong... Please *[edit]* your question with code.

Comment: Thank @sfdcfox I was able to pull it off with onblur. It was my js function that got all mixed up.

Comment: The onblur function worked. But if I click something from the dropdown, it won't be selected and would just disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You could try handling the tab key differently in your onkeyup action:

```
handleKeyUp : function(cmp, event){
    if(event.key === "Tab"){
        // do something...

    } else {
        // do something else...
    }
}
```

As for the other problem you mentioned in the comments -- the dropdown results disappearing when you try to click one: The input area is losing focus ("blurring") before the onclick event on the dropdown is registered. Instead of onclick, use onmousedown (if the tag supports it). It fires before onblur, so it should solve that problem.